# How to do a group by and then filter on a column in ArangoDB

Tags: graphql, arangodb

My object is below :

Document Name: **Test**

```
[{
        "_key": "12123",
        "custom_key": "1",
        value = "2"
    }, {
        "_key": "12124",
        "custom_key": "1",
        value = "3"
    }, {
        "_key": "12125",
        "custom_key": "2",
        value = "2"
    }, {
        "_key": "12126",
        "custom_key": "2",
        value = "5"
    }, {
        "_key": "12127",
        "custom_key": "2",
        value = "10"
    }
]
```

How to write an arango query to get the objects with maximum `value` group by `custom_key`?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, at the moment there is no `MAX_BY` aggregate function, but as a workaround you can use something like this:

```
FOR d IN docs
  COLLECT key = d.custom_key AGGREGATE v = MAX([d.value, d])
  RETURN { custom_key: key, doc: v[1] }
```

Comment: I want to return {custom_key : key , d}

Comment: Ah, ok. I have edited my answer accordingly. Please let me know if this is still not what you are looking for.